# Partial transpose/pivot dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-----+------+-------+-------+
| tom | dick | harry | type  |
+-----+------+-------+-------+
| 100 |  200 |   150 | type1 |
| 200 |  200 |   300 | type2 |
+-----+------+-------+-------+
```

I need to transform that to this:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| person | type1 | type2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
| tom    |   100 |   200 |
| dick   |   200 |   200 |
| harry  |   150 |   300 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

I've been going in circles on pivot, unpivot, melt, and stack, but it doesn't seem like any of those quite do what I want (although I may be missing something). Ideally I'd like to end up with something dynamic, so I don't have to hard code names Tom, Dick, and Harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not finding an official `unpivot()` or `melt()` function, but I was able to come up with this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val df = Seq(
    (100, 200, 150, "type1"),
    (200, 200, 300, "type2")
    ).toDF("tom", "dick", "harry", "type")

val columns = df.columns

df.flatMap(r => {
    val buf = ArrayBuffer[(String, String, Int)]()
    val t = r.getAs[String]("type")
    columns.foreach(c => {
        c match {
            case "type" =>
            case _ => buf += Tuple3(c, t, r.getAs[Int](c))
        }
    })
    buf.toIterable
}).toDF("person", "type", "value")
  .groupBy("person")
  .pivot("type")
  .agg(first("value"))
  .show()
```

This results in:

```
+------+-----+-----+
|person|type1|type2|
+------+-----+-----+
| harry|  150|  300|
|  dick|  200|  200|
|   tom|  100|  200|
+------+-----+-----+
```

This essentially takes two steps, first it "melts" the `DataFrame` down to having "person", "type", and "value" columns, then just pivots on person, grabbing the `first()` record in the group.

The number of columns you have can be arbitrary, but it does require a "type" column, and it requires all values to be of the same type.

Hopefully this generalizes well enough for your use case.

Comment: I get this exception:`java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. If I replace `Int` with `Long`, I get `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`.  Which doesn't seem to make sense to me. The datatypes for the actual dataframe are `Array((tom,LongType), (dick,LongType), (harry,LongType), (Type,StringType))`, if that matters.

Comment: BTW, I get this when I use it with my actual dataframe, if I use the made up data, it works perfectly.

Comment: Double check that you are operating on a `DataFrame` that only contains the interesting columns. Also verify the name of your "type" column. If it's a different name, then you'll have to adjust the code in both the `.getAs` and the `case`. This error could be experienced in this code if it encounters some other unexpected `StringType` column, or if the "type" column has a different name.

Comment: If you are able, sharing the schema of your actual `DataFrame` may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that gathers the name/value of columns to be unpivoted along with the pivot column value into a `struct`, flattens it, followed by a `groupBy/pivot` aggregation:

```
val df = Seq(
  (100, 200, 150, "type1"),
  (200, 200, 300, "type2")
).toDF("tom", "dick", "harry", "type")

val colsToUnpivot = Array("tom", "dick", "harry")
val colToPivot = "type"

val structCols = colsToUnpivot.map(cu => struct(
  lit(cu).as("name"), col(cu).as("cu"), col(colToPivot).as("cp")
))

df.
  withColumn("flattened", explode(array(structCols: _*))).
  groupBy($"flattened.name").pivot($"flattened.cp").agg(first($"flattened.cu")).
  show
// +-----+-----+-----+
// | name|type1|type2|
// +-----+-----+-----+
// |harry|  150|  300|
// | dick|  200|  200|
// |  tom|  100|  200|
// +-----+-----+-----+
```